# Is it possible to access a method from QMetaMethod in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

Assume that you have two classes `A` and `B` in QT C++. Your goal is to transfer data from `A` to `B` and `B` to `A`.

For `A` class, you have the ability to use the method `findChildren`. Assume that you have objects inside class `A` that you want to access and find out which value them have.
For that, you could use:

```
QDoubleSpinBox *item = findChild<QDoubleSpinBox*>("analogSingleInput" + index + "MaxDoubleSpinBox");
```

Here we say that you want to find the objects from `analogSingleInput0MaxDoubleSpinBox` to `analogSingleInputNMaxDoubleSpinBox` where `N` is a large number.

I can do that here with class `A`:

```
QDoubleSpinBox *item = findChild<QDoubleSpinBox*>("analogSingleInput" + index + "MaxDoubleSpinBox");
```

I want to have the value from `item`. To access the value, I can write `item->value()` and it will return a `double` back. OK good!

Now I want to insert that value to class `B`. Let's say that I have created an object called `b` from class `B`. And I want to use `QMetaObject` to find which type of index of the method I want to use inside `B`.

```
const QMetaObject *objB = b.metaObject();
int method_index = maxObject->indexOfMethod(("setAnalogSingleInput" + index + "Max").toStdString().c_str());
```

Above, the the index of methods `setAnalogSingleInput0Max` to `setAnalogSingleInputNMax` can be found .

And now I want to find the method from `B`.

```
QMetaMethod method = b->method(method_index);
```

Now what? How can I insert `item->value()` into `method` object so the object `b` will have that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [QMetaMethod::invoke](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetamethod.html#invoke-2) method:

```
method.invoke(b, Qt::DirectConnection, Q_ARG(double, item->value() ));
```

(where `b` is a pointer to instance of `B` class),
if the obtained method returns some value, Q_RETURN_ARG is needed before passed parameters:

```
RetType res;
method.invoke(b, Qt::DirectConnection, Q_RETURN_ARG(RetType,res), Q_ARG(double, item->value() ));
```

Comment: `iocalibrationwindow.cpp:83:23: error: cannot cast 'b' to its private base class 'QObject'
iocalibration.h:7:23: note: implicitly declared private here`.

Comment: `method.invoke(&b, Qt::DirectConnection, Q_ARG(double, item->value() ));
`

Comment: Do you think it's easier to use `invokeMethod` insead?

Comment: This is another possibility.

Comment: Yes! I understand now the function. https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod